# How to make the colormap correspond to the vertical coordinate?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar, scatter, colormap

Consider the following example:

```
x = linspace(0,3*pi,200);
y = cos(x) + rand(1,200);
c = linspace(1,10,length(x));
figure(); scatter(x,y,[],c);
colorbar
```

[image]

In this example, the color of the data points corresponds to the horizontal coordinate. Instead, I would like color to correspond to the vertical coordinate. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `y` as the color index:

```
scatter(x,y,[],y);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Abdullah I'm glad to hear that! If this answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).